# CSS Brightness on opacity

Tags: html, css, opacity, division, brightness

So i have a div and in that div i have a button and a text box. The div i have set with opacity of 0.5. Okay perfect, however i do not want all of the content in the div to be transparent. How can i make the textbox and button full brightness?

```
.bodybox {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: white;
    top: 160px;     
    width: 960px;
    height: 450px;
    z-index: 13;
    margin-left: 24.736842105263158%;
    margin-right: 24.736842105263158%;
    opacity: 0.1;}
```

This is what i have so far so you can see what i mean.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygLRj.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases rgba helped me. Substitute background value.

```
bodybox {
position:absolute;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
top: 160px;     
width: 960px;
height: 450px;
z-index: 13;
margin-left: 24.736842105263158%;
margin-right: 24.736842105263158%;
opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Comment: @nha How does this not attempt to answer the question? Why should we delete this answer? It doesn't even have a downvote..

Comment: @James sorry, deleted and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:after` attribute if you have an image

```
.bodybox {
   position: relative;
}

.bodybox:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/tandem.jpg); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.2;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Or,if you only have a background-color, you can use `rgba`:

```
.bodybox {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.1)
    top: 160px;     
    width: 960px;
    height: 450px;
    z-index: 13;
    margin-left: 24.736842105263158%;
    margin-right: 24.736842105263158%;
    }
```